# How to print out factorization of numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, so I have been doing an online website called cscircles to begin learning python. One of the exercises I was given tells me to do the following: "**If a × b = n, we call a × b a factorization of n. In this exercise, write a program that takes a positive integer n from input, and then outputs all factorizations of n; you should follow the formatting given by the following example for n=10:**

**1 times 10 equals 10**

**2 times 5 equals 10**

**5 times 2 equals 10**

**10 times 1 equals 10** ".

So, the code I wrote kind of does this, but all I'm able to get it to do is to print the factors. Here is the code I wrote and its output:

```
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            print(i)
        if n%i > 0:
            continue
```

Now this just outputs the factors, for example, if I input 10, it will give me this output:

"**1**

**2**

**5**"

So, my question is what should I change to make it so that if I input 10 it will give me this output:

"**1 times 10 equals 10**

**2 times 5 equals 10**

**5 times 2 equals 10**

**10 times 1 equals 10**"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must use range(1, n+1) and think about how to calculate the second factor.

Comment: Thanks so much, I fixed it using what you told me and got the code:

Comment: int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n%i == 0:
        print(i, "times", int(n/i), "equals", 10)
    if n%i > 0:
        continue

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the second factor from the first on the fly:

```
 n = int(input())
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            print("%s times %s is %s")%(i, n/i, n)
        if n%i > 0:
            continue
```

There are a few optimizations you could go for, like you only need to check for factors up to `n/2` before you have all of the individual numbers.

The statements '1 times 10 is 10' and '10 times 1 is 10' are equivalent, and you probably shouldn't print both - unless that's what they ask of you.